# Cannot get correct <option> length with scrapy

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to find details from [a product page](https://www.tradeinn.com/trekkinn/es/salewa-zapatillas-senderismo-wildfire-goretex/137984358/p?queryID=e224c91d2a4cf72a7d82864253fb692f&buscador_search). I need to count the available size options in the dropbox. however `len(response.selector.css('[id="tallas_detalle"]').css('option'))` yields 7 when on the site i can see 14. please help.

Answer (score 0):

CHecking the website as of today, I see the following HTML:

```
<select name="id_producte" id="tallas_detalle" onchange="javascript:actualitzar_dades_producte(this.value,1);">
  <option value="12600628"  >EU 41 Black Olive / Wallnut</option>
  <option value="12600629"  >EU 42 Black Olive / Wallnut</option>
  <option value="12600630"  >EU 42 1/2 Black Olive / Wallnut</option>
  <option value="12600632"  >EU 44 Black Olive / Wallnut</option>
  <option value="12600619"  >EU 44 1/2 Black Olive / Wallnut</option>
  <option value="12600621"  >EU 46 Black Olive / Wallnut</option>
  <option value="12600622"  >EU 46 1/2 Black Olive / Wallnut</option>
</select>
```

This accounts for 7 items only (as you are seeing in your scrapy query). Maybe they have an async request being issued to add more items to the `select` element. Maybe, because of some JS + CSS, they are duplicating the items in the screen (you mentioned 14). But Scrapy is working fine reading the HTML.